# How to block all followers except followed

Tags: twitter

I have a lot of followers due to spam. I want to block and unblock them all to make them unfollow me except ones I followed. how to do that? is there any script to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter does not offer a way to do it in their native web/mobile app. There are however some 3rd party Twitter applications which handle bulk blocking/unblocking. [**Blocktogether**](https://blocktogether.org/), although built for other purposes, might help you do the job.